# Freshdesk API: Attach dataurl as file using PHP and CURL

Tags: php, curl, freshdesk

I'm trying to create a ticket in Freshdesk with a screenshot as an attachment. Screenshot is captured in a canvas and converted to dataurl. And I'm using the following code to pass it to the Freshdesk API (V2)

```
$data = [
"description" => $messageBody,
"subject" => 'Bug Report from Client',
"email" => $replyTo,
"priority" => 1,
"status" => 2,
"attachments" => [
    [
        "type" => "file",
        "name" => "Screenshot",
        "content-type" => "image/png",
        "resource" => $dataUrl,
    ]
]
];

$url = "https://domain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets";
$apiKey = "key";
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $apiKey);
$resultStr = curl_exec($ch);
```

It results in the following error.

```
{
 field: "attachments", 
 message: "It should contain elements of type valid file format only", 
 code: "datatype_mismatch" 
}
```

Without the attachments field, the above code works fine. How do I fix this?

Comment: _"and converted to dataurl"_ - so you'll have to convert this back then, to the actual binary file contents.

Comment: @CBroe It's not a file. I'm taking a screenshot of the page using a javascript plugin called html2canvas, loading it to a canvas and then converting it to dataurl. Before I used to mail it using sendgrid PHP SDK and that used to work fine.

Comment: _"It's not a file."_ - but the API wants a "file", as in "file upload." And a data URI simply is something different.

Comment: @CBroe See, I know Datauri is different from a file. But with the Sendgrid API, I was able to pass the dataiurl and send it as an attachment. I just wanted to know if such a thing is possible with Freshdesk API or PHP or JS (I tried canvas.toBlob() instead of toDataURL() but that too results in the same error)

Comment: https://developers.freshdesk.com/api/#attachments says, _"Only files on your local machine can be attached using API."_ - so I'd take that to mean, it doesn't accept any URLs, data or otherwise. It must not necessarily be a _real_ local "file" though - the PHP examples they are giving, are using `curl_file_create` with a real local file, but as long as you send your request in the same format (i.e., an actual HTTP file upload), the _source_ of the data should not matter.

Comment: You do not show the contents of `$dataUrl`.